# Can we add app roles only for API service under Manifest using ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Can we add app roles only for API service under Manifest using ARM template?
If yes, please let me know to how to do so.
Any json reference?

Comment: Are you using AAD app for your API service or API management service?

Comment: AAD app only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If you want to use ARM template for updating AAD Application Manifest:*

Unfortunately, there are not ARM templates for Azure AD. You can see all references [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/). ARM templates are all for Azure Resources, not Azure AD.

However, you can still use Powershell [**Set-AzureADApplication**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0) to achieve automation to set AppRoles for AAD application:

```
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId <String> -AppRoles <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AppRole]>
```